# Where are Rally Class xtype Values Assigned

Tags: javascript, rally

My Goal: Build a class based on an existing Rally class.
My Objective: Create an xtype for my new class.

I've inspected the publicly available source for both the Rally Grid and Rally Tree Grid.   I see them referencing the xtypes of other classes that they use for their own implementations, but I do not see anywhere that their own xtype is declared.

Where are these xtype mappings created / maintained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly confusing implementation detail of ExtJS' component system.

xtypes are declared on a component class like so:

```
alias: 'widget.mythingy'
```

You an see the example of TreeGrid you mentioned in your post here:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/source/TreeGrid.html#Rally-ui-grid-TreeGrid

Once you define a component class with an alias which begins with `widget.` you'll then be able to reference it when adding to a container.

```
this.add({ xtype: 'mythingy' });
```